# What's Spanish for "Singalong"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, vocabulario-técnico

Como padre de un crío de dos años y medio, he ido ya a bastantes `singalongs`. En estas actividades los niños cantan lo que saben o lo que pueden (dependiendo de la edad) diferentes canciones.

Nunca me dio por buscar una traducción de `singalong` pensando que sería algo así como "canta conmigo" o "cantajuegos" (aunque creo que estos son artistas musicales en España), pero el otro día viendo un video en YouTube la artista decía a sus fans "let's have a little singalong". Así que es también un "singalong" cuando coreas o cantas las canciones de tu artista favorito en un concierto.

La definición del diccionario para singalong es:

> an informal occasion when people sing together in a group.

[Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=singalong) lo traduce como `acompañamiento`, pero a mi ese término me suena a "hacer los coros". En un concierto, tanto de críos como de adultos, alguien lleva la voz cantante (nunca mejor dicho) y otros le siguen o acompañan, cierto, pero de acuerdo a la definición se pueden dar muchas otras circunstancias (como en un coro o en una improvisación) donde no hay una persona o grupo que sirva de referencia a los demás.

¿Hay alguna traducción para `singalong` (o `sing-along`) en español?

Comment: "CantaJuego" no es un grupo, sino [un proyecto pedagógico](http://www.cantajuego.com/el-proyecto/) que desarrolla la psicomotricidad y las relaciones sociales de los niños entre 0 y 6 años, usando la música. El grupo que interpreta las canciones se llama EnCanto. En todo caso, no creas que es una mala opción como palabra para designar a los "karaokes" para niños, aunque un CantaJuego tiene más de hacer coreografías que de cantar en realidad.

Answer (score 6):

Otra posibilidad para el singalong está en el uso del verbo [`corear`](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ArpFJsZ). Segun la RAE (la 5ª entrada en particular):

> 1. tr. Componer música para ser cantada con acompañamiento de coros.
> 2. tr. Acompañar o embellecer con coros una composición musical.
> 3. tr. Dicho de varias personas: Asentir sumisamente al parecer ajeno.
> 4. tr. Aclamar o aplaudir algo.
> 5. tr. Dicho de varias personas: Cantar, recitar o hablar algo a la vez. Corear la lección.

Answer (score 3):

En español, lo normal sería ajustar la frase para usar el verbo "cantar". Usando un ejemplo parecido al que indicas:

> Now let's have a little singalong!

Posibles traducciones serían:

> Ahora ¡vamos a cantar!
>   ¡Ahora cantemos juntos!

En el caso específico en que estemos usando *singalong* en el sentido de *karaoke* (he visto usarlo así en varias ocasiones, sobre todo en vídeos de internet), en español igual que en inglés se usa la palabra japonesa, karaoke.