# Uso y connotaciones de "Memo" en Hispanoamérica

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, hispanoamérica, nombres-propios, insultos

El otro día llevé a mis hijos a un *[<strike>singalong</strike> canta conmigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19721/5481)*. El grupo (un dúo) se presentó al principio de la función, y me llamó la atención que el nombre de pila de uno de ellos era "Memo". El grupo cantó canciones en inglés, español, portugués y mezcla de inglés y español. Al finalizar la función<sup>1</sup> dijeron de nuevo sus nombres y lugar de procedencia (ambos eran de países latinoamericanos, aunque de países distintos. Ella era de El Salvador; él creo que era de México, pero no estoy seguro).

Lo que me llamó la atención sobre la naturalidad con la que alguien recibe el nombre de pila de Memo (o alguien se refiere a otra persona por tal nombre), es que en España "memo" tiene connotaciones peyorativas.

> **[memo, ma](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Oreedk3%7COrf8vct)**
>
> 1. adj. Tonto, simple, mentecato. U. t. c. s.

Aunque también se indica que en algunos países es un acortamiento de "memorando":

> 1. m. Chile. memorando (‖ comunicación diplomática).
> 2. m. Guat. y Hond. memorando (‖ informe).

Entiendo que "Memo" puede ser un acortamiento de un nombre más largo, como *Fede* lo es de Federico, *Alex* de Alejandro, etc.

A mí se me hace extraño tanto usar como nombre de pila para alguien "Memo" como usar ese acortamiento para un nombre más largo. Sin embargo investigando un poco he visto que "Memo" sí parece usarse en algunos lugares como nombre de pila.

¿No tiene "memo" en Hispanoamérica las connotaciones negativas de la acepción mostrada en el DRAE ("Tonto, simple")? Porque no me resulta intuitivo que alguien quiera usar ese nombre o acortamiento (para sí mismo u otros) si las tiene.

---

1: Durante la función pensé que o bien yo había oído mal, y el nombre era "Nemo" o similar o bien que ellos no eran de países hispanoparlantes.

Comment: Memo es diminutivo de Guillermo en México

Comment: Gracias por la información. En España son "_Guilles_". Entiendo ahora de donde de donde viene el diminutivo o acortamiento, aunque no del todo el uso. En España llamar a alguien "Memo" es insultarle.

Comment: @Diego mi hijo mayor se llama Guillermo y el menor cuando intenta pronunciar su nombre dice "emmo" o "memmo", así que entiendo que el diminuto "Memo" simplemente intenta reproducir ese habla infantil, para que a los niños les sea más fácil pronunciar el nombre.

Comment: *Memo* en Argentina es como indica el DRAE para Chile, *memorando*, aunque se usa poco y nada. No tiene otra connotación. Aquí los Guillermos son *Guille* o *Willy*.

Comment: Ejemplo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillermo_Ochoa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En Colombia a las personas con el nombre **Guillermo** se les dice cariñosamente **Memo**.
Hasta donde sé **Memo** no se usa en el registro de nacimiento (o nombre de pila ) de una persona.

Nunca se usa con el significado de tonto ni tiene connotaciones peyorativas.

Es también posible escuchar (aunque poco) la palabra **memo** para referirse a a un **memorando**.

Un ejemplo es el presentador colombo-argentino residente en Colombia y conocido artísticamente en la televisión colombiana como [Memo Orozco](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memo_Orozco_(humorista)).

**Memo** es similar en su uso en Colombia a otras palabras para llamar cariñosamente o en diminutivo a las personas: **Pacho** a los que se llaman **Francisco**, **Pepe** a los que se llaman **José**, **Chavela** a las que se llaman **Isabel**, **Lupe** a las que se llaman **Guadalupe**.

Humor:
Si en inglés **Bill** es el diminutivo de **William** y **William** se traduce en español como **Guillermo**, y si además la palabra en inglés **gates** se traduce al español como **puertas**, entonces si **Bill Gates** hubiese nacido en Colombia sería **Memo Puertas** .

Comment: Puedes agregar México y Chile a tu respuesta.

Comment: En Chile también se podría usar con sentido peyorativo (depende del contexto y la intención) queriendo decir **tonto** o **lento de reacción**, además de ser abreviatura de memorandum y de apócope de algún nombre. También recuerdo la expresión **dar o pegar un memo**, que es unpequeño palmetazo en la parte posterior de la cabeza o en la frente

Comment: @RosieM.Banks Es una conocida pieza de humor regional y esta puesta como ejemplo del uso en Colombia de **Memo** para referirse a las personas llamadas **Guillermo.**

Comment: @RosieM.Banks, cuando escribo lo de "nombre de pila" me refiero que la persona NO es registrada con el nombre "Memo" se registra con "Guillermo"; esto es similar a decirle "Pacho" a quien se llama "Francisco", o decirle "Pepe" a quien se llama "José".